# using VBA, how to remove the addidtional repeated characters at last

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have multiple rows, I need to join with "@#" characters at end of every cell value, 
 I am able add this characters but at the end it is printing extra characters(@#)

My excel file: From this excel file, I need to join the values by @# for each cell and feed into notepad

[Excel File for Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOf65.png)

My output should be:(Actual and Expected)

[Actual and Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pjPs.png)

Here Is my code:

```
sub join()
dim LRow as long
dim LCol as long
Dim str1 as string
Dim str2 as string
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
 plik = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "BL2ASIS" & ws1.Name & ".txt"
 Open plik For Output As 2
With ws1
LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LCol = LCol - 2
slast = vbNullString


str2 = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Cells(n, "A").Resize(1, 2).Value)), "")
str1 = str2 & Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Cells(n, "C").Resize(1, LCol).Value)), "@#") & "@#"
str1 = Replace(str1, "=", vbNullString)
str1 = Replace(str1, "@#@#", "@#")


Print #2, str1
End with

end sub
```

Comment: Just noticed you are using Replace. And that is not working?

Comment: is the problem where you add & "@#" after Join? Have you checked you don't end up somewhere with @#@#@#  + ?

Comment: I imagine it is because empty strings are still being concatenated with "@#"... Perhaps try checking the length of the string is more than 0 before adding the "@#"

Comment: @QHarr  Yeah U r right, I used replace, but it works only for two characters(@#@#) then it replaces with one time(@#), if there is 4 times I feed this item(@#@#@#@#) then it replaces with one time(@#@#)

Comment: then that is your problem right there.

Comment: Based on my requirement, If it is empty for many columns then it has to print only one time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace your line:

```
str1 = Replace(str1, "@#@#", "@#")
```

with:

```
Do Until Len(str1) = Len(Replace(str1, "@#@#", "@#"))
    str1 = Replace(str1, "@#@#", "@#")
Loop
```

which will keep applying the replace until there is no point in doing so (i.e. the length doesn't change)

---

**EDIT**

Sorry to alter an accepted answer, but I've noticed that you might want to keep instances of @#@# if they occur somewhere *other than at the end* of the row. If you do then the following would be better, as it only trims the right-most characters:

```
Do Until Right(str1, 4) <> "@#@#"
    str1 = Left(str1, Len(str1) - 2)
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine now based on the above Do Until loop

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to replace more than one instance.

Note:

1. If you want to replace repeats only at the end of the string then change regex pattern to `(@#){2,}$` . This will deal with 2 or more occurrences.
2. If only worried about two occurrences at end, use `(@#)\1$`

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub TEST()
    Dim testString As String, pattern As String
    testString = "xxxxx@#@#"
    testString = RemoveChars(testString)
    Debug.Print testString
End Sub

Public Function RemoveChars(ByVal inputString As String) As String

    Dim regex As Object, tempString As String
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With regex
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .pattern = "(@#){2,}"
    End With

    If regex.TEST(inputString) Then
        RemoveChars = regex.Replace(inputString, "@#")
    Else
        RemoveChars = inputString
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: thanks, I tried the above code, this is also works fine

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting repeated characters is because you are joining empty array elements. An alternative to removing repeated delimiters is to use a UDF to only join non null values. Please see below for such a function.

```
Sub TestJoin()
    Dim r As Range: Set r = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B12")
    Dim arr() As Variant
    arr = Application.Transpose(r)
    Debug.Print NonNullJoin(arr, "#") & "#"
End Sub

Function NonNullJoin(SourceArray() As Variant, Optional Delimiter As String = " ") As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim i As Long: For i = 0 To UBound(SourceArray)
        If CStr(SourceArray(i)) <> "" Then NonNullJoin = _
            IIf(NonNullJoin <> "", NonNullJoin & Delimiter & CStr(SourceArray(i)), CStr(SourceArray(i)))
    Next i
End Function
```